# Semantic UI react dropdown search allowAddition, how to distinguish the addition in onchange event?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

In my program, if user select items in dropdown, the onchange event will trigger api call to autofill the rest of fields. But if user add its own item in dropdown, I need to distinguish it and do my onchange event a little differently.

But it seems like the onchange event props don't give out any info on whether this selection (the value field) is an addition. The onAddItem function happens after onchange so it won't help either. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The onChange event doesn't currently indicate if the value is new, but you can easily determine that by looping through the options.

```
dropwDownChangeHandler(event, data) {
    let optionIsExisting = false;
    data.options.forEach(option => {
      if (option.value === data.value) optionIsExisting = true;
     });
    console.log(optionIsExisting);
}
```

Comment: There is also a `onAddItem` event. The challenge with this one is it fires after the change handler, so it may not be a good option.